# Can anyone explain why strtotime('cast') returns a value?

Tags: php, casting, strtotime

Not really an issue (although it is conflicting with an if() statement we have), but when you type in strtotime('cast'), it returns an actual value that defaults to today's date.

I was just wondering if anyone knew what significance the word cast has when it comes to time functions

Thanks!

Comment: OK so firstly lolwut, and secondly `strtotime('c')` and `strtotime('cat')` also return values :-S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It maps to the [timezone offset for "Australia/Adelaide"](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/36f2c8249b5d37d5923621a7d202538d46a5d30d/ext/date/lib/timezonemap.h#L390).

Example:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), "\n",
     date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("cast")), "\n",
     date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("Australia/Adelaide"));
```

Prints:

```
2016-08-25 10:48:44
2016-08-25 01:18:44
2016-08-25 01:18:44
```

Comment: Exactly. So basically any time zone abbreviation listed here http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ should be usable in strtotime as a “relative date”

Comment: Hm, that sounds like a rather fuzzy implementation to me; I can’t imagine why this would be mapped to a different timezone than the one it actually represents? Especially since PHP knows the timezone `Antarctica/Casey`, as http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.antarctica.php shows.